# Java intellji Invalid maximum heap size

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>
> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096M
>
> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

i have this error when i start to excute my program with **intellji**

in **edite configration** i change **Vm options to** :

> -ea -Dmodules=core,tables,corenlp -Xms4096M -Xmx4096M  .

i want to read some large data
and it give me this error

i change the value to  -Xms4095M -Xmx4095M
it give me error when excute

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for 4188160KB object heap

this program want a 5G of ram

i have 2 ram 4G and the win7 let me use all of 8G.

but here i cant put a value bigger than 4095M !!
how i can solve it?

Comment: I suppose that you use 32 bit version of java. Try run idea64.exe

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241105.

Comment: Change your project SDK to 64-bit version.

Comment: thanks everybody , yes my sdk version is 32 bit ..
i instal 64 bit and it works

Answer (score 1):

**Error:** **Intellij heap size snap**

This answer is only for the **linux/debian** users.

So, I changed the max heap size from 750m to 2048m. When i changed this, I was unable to start the intellij.

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx2048m
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I installed the intellij by the help of **snap**. So, the contents of all the snaps where installed at **/snap/intellij**.

These contents were **read-only**. So, you cannot change the **vmoptions** here.

The actual customized **vmoptions** is present in the **user directory**.

The name of the directory is **.IntelliJIdea{Year.Version}/config**. Some of the operating systems hide this directory. So, you need to **enable show the hidden files**

Now, you will find the **idea64.vmoptions** file. Edit this file to the **decrease the memory.**

Comment: PPL should not vote down this answer. This actually help me to figure out my issue. Even though I did not follow this answer end to end but at least it gives me a hint which lead me to figure out my issue.